# Can I use future values to smooth past value using moving average technique?

Tags: moving-average

Assume I have 10 values,

[5,4,6,7,3,2,1,3,4,6],

If I use regular moving average with a window size of 5 (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.mean.html) then I get ,
[nan,
nan,
nan,
nan,
5,
4.4,
3.8,
3.2,
2.6,
3.2].

Here I used first 5 values which are [5, 4, 6, 7, 3] to calculate the 5th value which is 5 in the newly created window.

What if, I used the first 5 values to calculate the first value?

Then the new window will look like this [5, 4.4, 3.8, 3.2, 2.6, 3.2, nan, nan, nan, nan]. Is it acceptable to do?

Comment: It depends on your use case. As an example, for visualization (drawing charts) I'd duplicate values which are at the bounds.

Comment: I want to do it for regression. I will shift up the rows in input variables but I will not change anything in output variable. for example suppose this is input variable [5,4,6,7,3,2,1,3,4,6], and this is output variable [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
After filtering, input variable becomes [nan, nan, nan, nan, 5, 4.4, 3.8, 3.2, 2.6, 3.2]. But I will shift it up,  [5, 4.4, 3.8, 3.2, 2.6, 3.2, nan, nan, nan, nan] but output variables order will not change.

Comment: Please include the exact use scenario and the expected results in the question. And since you're new, read the Tour (Under the question mark icon at the top right)